# Updating replaced OneToMany ArrayList's cascade objects of an entity

Tags: playframework, ebean

I am using PlayFramework 2.2.1 / Java / Ebean / MySQL
Thera are two classes (entities):

```
@Entity
public class Cart extends Model{
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    public int id;
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public List <Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
public class Item extends Model{
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    public int id;
    public String name;
}
```

I'm trying to update existing records in DB table with changes I make to Item objects inside ArrayList of Cart object.
Problem - Ebean doesn't update, but adds a new record in table if I **replace object** in items ArrayList, but it does update existing record if I **change field values** of an Item object directly:

```
    Cart cart = new Cart();
    Item item1 = new Item(); item1.name = "Banana";
    Item item2 = new Item(); item2.name = "Peach";
    cart.items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    cart.items.add(item1);
    cart.items.add(item2);
    cart.save();
```

No problems with saving, but when I try to read and update:

```
    Cart cart = Cart.find.all().get(0);
    cart.items.get(0).name="Orange";                //updates perfectly
    Item item3 = new Item(); item3.name = "Apple";  
    cart.items.set(1, item3);                       //adds additional third record
    cart.update();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing everything right.
If you want to update something, you need to load it, modify and save.
If you want to add something, you create new object and save it.

Ebean look at @Id value of object, not at the index of object in list. If your object don't have an id, Ebean creates new record in the table.

Maybe, if you create new object with the same id, Ebean will update it. For exmaple

```
Item item3 = new Item();
item3.id = cart.items.get(1).id;
item3.name = "Apple";
```

But 1) I can't tell you if it will work 2) It is **really** hackish and you **really** don't need to use this.

If you want to modify objects in `items`, you need to load it and modify loaded objects, it's the right way.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem but found the solution was based around using the setters to change the values rather than accessing the fields directly.  I assume there is some magic being injected into the methods to inform the subsystems of objects changes, allowing updates etc.

So yea, I'd write the original example like this (assuming the database is empty beforehand):

```
Cart cart = new Cart();
Item item1 = new Item(); item1.setName("Banana");
Item item2 = new Item(); item2.setName("Peach");
cart.items = new ArrayList<Item>();
cart.items.add(item1);
cart.items.add(item2);
cart.save();

Cart cart = Cart.find.all().get(0);

Item item1 = cart.items.get(0);
item1.setName("Orange");

Item item2 = cart.items.get(1);
item2.setName("Apple");  

cart.update();
```

You could also change the last 3 lines to:

```
Item item2 = new Item();
item2.setId(1); // this way Ebean will do the update
item2.setName("Apple");

cart.update();
```

Hope that helps.